# Proper dockerfile for google app engine with libraries

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, dockerfile

I'm trying to move my app from Google App Engine to Compute Engine with managed VMs. According to documentation, I would only need to add `vm: true`
 and different instances specification to my app.yaml to get things working.

Unfortunately, I get `ImportError: libxslt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` when trying to import lxml. I've got a list of needed libraries in app.yaml, and it works when I deploy my app to App Engine.

On the next step, I tried to create my own docker file, which will install all the needed libraries. Now it looks like this:

```
FROM beta.gcr.io/google_appengine/python-compat
RUN apt-get -q update && \
 apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q \
   python2.7 python-pip python-dev build-essential git mercurial \
   libffi-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev \
   libxslt1-dev libpq-dev libmysqlclient-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev \
   libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev libpng12-dev && \
 apt-get clean && rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*_*
RUN pip install lxml==2.3.5
ADD . /app
```

And now I'm getting new error `ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/vmagent/app/lib/lxml/etree.so)`. Adding libc6 to packages list for apt-get doesn't change anything, so I'm out of the ideas.

So how can I get my app working here?

Comment: what version does show the output of `ldd --version` command running on your instance? It should be 2.14 or newer.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/537683/how-to-fix-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found/537694#537694

Answer (score 0):

You must install this package, this package is responsible for libc.so.6

```
yum install libtidy glibc
```